# Adding NavigationController Won't show back button

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to add the "Back button" to a couple of my view to a specific view that come before them.

View A has 2 buttons, to view B and C, I want B and C (And all following views) to have the "back button", but I don't want it to appear once I'm in view A.

In this example, I'll only show what I've done with view A and B.

[image: Views A and B]

I added the navigation controller between A and B, and as you can see, "Shows Navigation Bar" is ticked on. The segue between A and B is "present modally".
For some reason it doesn't show in my storyboard, but view A is a tabbed view connected to a tabbarController. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your root view controller (first one, basically) needs to be a UINavigationController in order to have that navigation bar and back button work natively.

Also, presenting a UIViewController modally does not show a navigation bar (and subsequently the back button). Only when you push a UIViewController onto the navigation stack will the navigation bar and back button show.

Here is an example of pushing a view controller from another view controller that is within a UINavigationController:

```
 func buttonPressed() {
     let nextViewController = UIViewController()
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)

     // As long as your navigation bar is not set to hidden, 
     // doing this will push nextViewController onto the navigation stack 
     // and show the back button + navigation bar.
 }
```

Comment: But it says "push" is deprecated ?

Comment: Ok I tried it, but the view won't load because it says it found nil while unwrapping an optional value in this line : // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.ProductsCollection.delegate = self , in "viewDidLoad". Didn't ProductsCollection was instantiated when using let myProducts = MyProductsView() ?

Comment: @Ofri Please provide the code you used to push the new view controller and where it is causing an issue. I will be able to help better, then.

Comment: Seems I was able to fix it. Segue needs to be from view to view and not through button, and choose "push segue". Then button needs to activate segue

Comment: @Ofri Yes, segue is one way to do it. Glad you got it!

Comment: Any chance you can help me with another problem I'm having ? :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137461/nserror-domain-com-google-httpstatus-code-404